# How to track an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

Is there a way keep track of an Intent? Suppose an Intent was broadcast through senOrderedBroadcast(myIntnet, null) now   how to keep track of this intent as to which application received it or is processing it.

thnx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an IntentExtra which is a unique Id associated with it and hence track it , when it reaches a particular receiver or Activity.

Comment: Extras would be used by the receiving application, ryt? how can the sender of an Intent(Intent is being Broadcast) get information that which application received the intnet

Comment: @noob your best bet is to hook the intent sending and receiving functions for instance with Frida. If you're tracking them across apps it becomes harder as you would need to hook all apps that can handle the intent. Mind, all of this works only for debugging purposes.